# Ansible: yum module's "state" parameter

Tags: ansible

In the docs of Ansible,
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html#options

There is a comment about "state" parameter:

> Whether to install (present or installed, latest), or remove (absent or removed) a package.

**My question is:**

Are there any differences between the 3 choices(present, installed, latest)?Which one should I use when I run these commands below?

```
yum clean all && yum makecache 
yum upgrade
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yum `clean` is not available in the `yum` module, so best to use the `command` module:

```
- name: Perform a yum clean
  command: /usr/bin/yum clean all
```

For `makecache` you can use the `yum` module:

```
- name: Ensure the yum package index is up to Date
  yum:
    update_cache: yes
    name: '*'
    state: latest
```

And also use the `yum` module for `upgrade`:

```
- name: upgrade all packages
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
```

Answer (score 2):

`present` (`installed` is the same, but deprecated) ensures that package is in the system. If it is there, module exits unchanged; If it is not, package is installed and module exits with changed state.

`latest` ensures that the latest available version of package is in the system. If the latest version already installed, module exits unchanged; If it is not installed or version is not up-to-date, module installs the latest versions and exits with changed state.

Example from the docs:

```
- name: upgrade all packages
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
```

Comment: When I want to run "yum clean all && yum makecache",how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ways to clean on the yum module. You just have to use command module:

```
- name: Clean all packages
  command: yum clean all && yum makecache
```